# Unencrypted connection to SQL Server throws handshake error

Tags: sql-server, ssl, .net-core, containers, tls1.2

I have a .NET 6 service running in a container (based on the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal` image). When my service needs to talk to the SQL Server database, I must set `SECLEVEL=1` in my OpenSSL config. I run the following when creating the container (taken from this github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/776#issuecomment-825418533)

```
RUN sed -i '1i openssl_conf = default_conf' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf && echo "\n[ default_conf ]\nssl_conf = ssl_sect\n[ssl_sect]\nsystem_default = system_default_sect\n[system_default_sect]\nMinProtocol = TLSv1.2\nCipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

If I don't, I get this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

But... my connection string has not set anything about encrypt or anything else that indicates that I must make an encrypted connection. And when I look at EF Core 6 or less, `Encrypt=False` is the default. So if you don't do anything explicit, I assume that the connection is **not** encrypted.

My connection string looks like this

```
Server=123,456;Database=123;User ID=123;PWD=123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

On the .NET side I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.13, which has a dependency on Microsoft.Data.SqlCliet 2.1.4. Both of these has encrypt=false as default for the connection strings.

And that's where I'm unable to understand what happens.

If the connection is **not** encrypted, why do I have to set `SECLEVEL=1` to avoid handshake errors? Why does a handshake even happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SQL Server you are connecting to is configured with force encryption, TLS/SSL will be used for all communication regardless of whether the client requests encryption or not.

Even if encryption is not required by client or server, [login packets for the credential exchange are still encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#login-packet-encryption-vs-data-packet-encryption). The setup needed to do so occurs as part of the pre-login handshake as described in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237106/how-encryption-in-sql-login-authentication-works). This introduces the TLS/SSL requirement.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly. The reason I need to set SECLEVEL=1, is that the SQL Server on the other side, must be using a self signed cert, AND SQL Server 2016 or lower, as the self signed cert is SHA1, resulting in SECLEVEL=1.
From the applications side I cannot do anything, it is the responsebility of the SQL Server, and until the certs SECLEVEL is raised, I will have to manually trust SECLEVEL=1, in order to do the initial handshake?

Comment: @Squazz, specify `TrustServerCertificate=True` in the connection string if the SQL Server cert is self-signed. SQL 2016 supports TLS 1.2 out-of-the box so SECLEVEL=1 is needed only if TLS 1.2 is disabled on the server or a common cypher suite could not be negotiated.

Comment: sorry, I see I hadn't stated that previously. I am already using TrustServerCertificate=True; and is still needing the SECLEVEL=1 in the container. As I also state "MinProtocol = TLSv1.2" I guess the last bit is "a common cypher suite could not be negotiated". Why this happens I don't know. It's a default install of SQL 2016, and the certificate is the default self-signed.

Comment: @Squazz, have you installed SQL 2016 SP3? For troubleshooting, try an [XE trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305966/monitoring-sql-server-encryption-with-extended-events) to capture the TLS handshake messages.

Comment: Yup, SP3 is installed. I only have read access to the database, so won't be able to make an XE trace.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer from Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75484423/1955317) answers why the handshake occurs.

The reason I need to set SECLEVEL=1, is that the SQL Server on the other side, must be using a self signed cert, AND is a SQL Server 2016 or lower, as the self signed cert for SQL Server 2016 and lower is SHA1, resulting in the application needing to accept SECLEVEL=1.

From the applications side it cannot do anything, it is the responsebility of the SQL Server to offer a better certificate. And until the certificate offered is based on SHA256, the application will have to manually trust SECLEVEL=1, in order to do the initial handshake.

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't require encryption, try to add `;Encrypt=false` in the connection string.
I had some project (.NET 6) that doesn't work without it. Also if the docs state that false is the default.